# No overload matches this call in Redux Saga effect

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a simple Redux Saga file, where I run `takeLatest()` Saga effect. But typescript gives me an error:

```
(alias) const getMovies: ActionCreatorWithoutPayload<string>
import getMovies
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TakeableChannel<unknown>'.ts(2769)
effects.d.ts(291, 17): The last overload is declared here.
```

Where is problem please? I was looking for some available solutions on the internet but without success.

**TYPES**

```js
export type Movie = { title: string; year: number };

export type MovieState = {
  moviesList: Movie[];
  totalResults: number;
};

export type MoviesFetchType = {
  payload: { query: string; page: number };
};

export type MoviesType = {
  status: number;
  json: () => number;
};

export type FormatedMoviesType = {
  Search: Movie[];
  totalResults: number;
};
```

**SAGA + SLICE**

```js
import { call, put, fork, takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {Movie, MovieState, MoviesFetchType, MoviesType, FormatedMoviesType} from "./types";

// SLICE

const initialState = {
  moviesList: [{}],
  totalResults: 0
} as MovieState;

const movieSlice = createSlice({
  name: "movie",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getMovies(name) {
      return name;
    },
    setMovies: (state, action: PayloadAction<Movie[]>) => {
      state.moviesList = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

const { getMovies, setMovies } = movieSlice.actions;

// SAGA

function* moviesFetch({ payload }: MoviesFetchType) {
  const { query, page } = payload;
  const movies: MoviesType = yield call(() =>
    fetch(`https://example.com/&s=${query}&page=${page}`)
  );
  const formatedMovies: FormatedMoviesType = yield movies.json();
  yield put(setMovies(formatedMovies["Search"]));
}

function* moviesSaga() {
  // HERE IS PROBLEM
  yield takeLatest(getMovies.type, moviesFetch);
}

export const moviesSagas = fork(moviesSaga);
```

`getMovies.type` give me an error: No overload matches this call. What is it and How to solve it?

Thank you!

// EDIT - add Slice
// EDIT 2 - merge into one file

Comment: please provide reproducible exmaple with all imports

Comment: Please add minimum reproducible example, no need to add all your file dependencies. Try to reduce it to one file.  Further more, you did not add `movieSlice` file

Comment: I edited and it should be fine. I hope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `MoviesFetchType`. The `takeLatest` definition expects the first param of the saga to be an object which includes the `type` property. Since there is no `type` property in `MoviesFetchType` it doesn't match the expected type and fails.

Try using:

```js
export type MoviesFetchType = {
  payload: { query: string; page: number };
  type: string;
};
```

or if you don't want to have redux related info in that type then perhaps:

```js
export type MoviesFetchType = {
  query: string;
  page: number;
};
// ...
function* moviesFetch({ payload }: {type: string; payload: MoviesFetchType}) {
```

Comment: Great! It works, thank you for devoting your time to my problem. Ďakujem Martin ;)